# Play get json request parameters

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, datatables, playframework-2.4

I am using [jQuery Datatable](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) plugin, I would like to get the default parameters sent to the server in my controller action as shown in the link.

Here is my ajax request code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable( {
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "getTable",
                "type": "POST"
            }
        } );
    } );
```

Here is my controller action code

```
public Result ajaxDisplayTable() {
        Logger.info("This is just another method for ajax post action call...");
        String userAgent = request().getHeader("User-Agent");
        Logger.info("user agent =  "+ userAgent);
        RequestBody body = request().body();
        Logger.info("bare body = "+ body);
        Logger.info("json ... "+ body.asJson());
        Logger.info("body as json = " + body.asText());
        return ok("Got json: " );
}
```

request is sent to the server and the action method is called body is printed, but the body.asJson() and body.asText() is always null as shown in below image.
[image]

And as shown in below image 
[image]
[image]

the request paramters are passed as application/json, correct me here If I am wrong, then why body.asJson() is null, how to get all the request parameters in action method? I am using Play 2.4.2 version(Damiya).

Comment: See `Content-type`, it's `x-www-form-urlencoded`, it's not JSON. Maybe you should use `body.asFormUrlEncoded()` instead, see [Default body parser: AnyContent](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaBodyParsers#Default-body-parser:-AnyContent)?

Comment: What is that accept : application/json?

Comment: This is what browser will accept as a response, see [Accept](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRQ_Headers.html#z3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You request is sent as `application/x-www-form-url-encoded`, see `Content-type` header. You need to use `body.asFormUrlEncoded()` instead of `body.asJson()`.

```
public Result ajaxDisplayTable() {
    RequestBody body = request().body();
    final Map<String, String[]> values = body.asFormUrlEncoded();
    final String valDraw = values.get("draw")[0];
}
```

See [Body parsers](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaBodyParsers#Default-body-parser:-AnyContent) for more information.